# Pulley rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

[image]

In the given arrangement, the friction in between the string and the pulley is enough to avoid slipping and the string is light. On the basis of these assumptions, would the tension in the upper part of the string (ie. the arc BC)  be 0? Because AB is in equilibrium as the frictional force equals the tension in AB acting on AB by the mass m2, the same for DC, hence there is no force on the part BC and thus the tension should be 0.
Am I correct?, any help will be appreciated

Comment: No,  its not in equilibrium if both the masses are different even if you have infinite friction between string and pulley. Do you know pulleys can rotate about their axis too?

Comment: Ya, I'm saying that on the part AB of the string no net force must act as the string is massless

Comment: there is a net force m2g-m1g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that friction can appear is for there to be tension, since it is tension that will give rise to the normal force needed for friction.

Now if we note that the friction must result in a difference in tension between the left and right strings (if the masses are different) then there will be a continuous change in tension. The normal force at every point is proportional to the local tension, and in the limit where the friction is "just enough" this means that there will be an exponential decay in the tension from the high end to the low end.

The diagram that helps explain this is the following:

[image]

If you consider just a bit of string that is touching a small arc of the pulley, then there is a normal force $F_n$ due to the tension in the string that is proportional to the local tension $T$ and the angle $d\theta$, and that gives rise to a differential friction $dF = \mu F_n$. As a consequence, the tension $T_2$ will be larger than $T_1$ by that amount: $T_2 = T_1 + dF$. When the angle $d\theta$ becomes very small, you can consider $T_1 = T_2 = T$ for the purpose of computing the normal force, $F_n = Td\theta$.

See if you can derive the rest from there.

Comment: In my book, in such problems, they have assumed that the tension on either end will provide the torque on the pulley. In this case the tension in BC must be zero, right?

Comment: No - if there is no tension in BC, there is no normal force and hence no friction. The above is true whether it results in an acceleration of the pulley or not.

Comment: Then what are they assuming, when they say that the frictional force at B is equal to the tension in AB, and at C is equal to the tension in DC?Im just real confused here

Comment: It makes no sense to say the frictional force at B is equal to the tension in AB. Who are "they" that say this?

Comment: The frictional force will act on the pulley and provide the torque for rotation right?

Comment: By "they"  I mean all my professors and textbooks

Comment: The integral of frictional force from B to C should provide the difference in tension between B and C. There is no basis for saying that all the friction is concentrated at a single point, and that there is no tension in the rest of the string. That wouldn't make physical sense not only because of the discontinuity it creates, but because there can be no normal force between string and pulley unless there is a tension on both sides of a point (such as point B, for example).

Comment: ya so the total frictional force = |T(AB) - T(CD)|. and also dT =zTdθ (z=Coeffecient of friction). Which on integration gives T=e^(zθ + ln(T(AB)))

Comment: θ is ange with horizontal,so by putting θ=π we should be able to evaluate T(CD), right?

Comment: The equation you employed for the frictional force in terms of the normal force only applies when there is kinetic friction (i.e., slippage).  For static friction, there is no such relationship, except at incipient slippage.  Otherwise there has to be a $\leq$ sign.  So the development you presented is only correct if the string is slipping over the entire surface of the pulley.

Comment: @ChesterMiller  I did state _in the limit where the friction is "just enough"_ - and note that even if the local coefficient of friction is greater and therefor there will be a greater drop in tension per unit length, this will then mean that there is comparatively less normal force and thus less friction. What that means is that you can have the exponential change in tension happen over a shorter distance, possibly followed by a region of constant tension. But I see no argument where tension goes to zero and then magically increases again.

Comment: If the two masses are equal (and the system is allowed to be in static equilibrium), then there will be exponential decay of tension away from the initial contact points (case of wrap angle of 180 degrees).  As the coefficient of friction is made higher (mathematically), the tension on each side will decay to essentially zero over a smaller and smaller arc away from each contact point.  In the limit of a very high coefficient of friction, all the decay will occur immediately adjacent to the two contact points, and the tension will be essentially zero over the rest of the wrap.

Answer (score 0):

If the pulley is free to rotate and perfectly frictionless then the tension in the string is the same throughout, from A to D.  So the tension in BC is not zero.

You are correct in your comment stating that the net force on BC is zero, because the tensions in AB pulling right and in CD pulling left are equal.  However, the net force acting on section BC is not the same thing as the tension in section BC.  It can be in static equilibrium while still being in tension.

Comment: The tension may not be the same throughout, at B or C if we consider the part of the string which is in contact with the pulley, then it will have a frictional force upwards, the tension in AB downwards and the tension in BC upwards, and the forces on this part must be balanced due to the mass less nature of the string, hence the tension in BC will be less than that in AD if the frictional force is non zero.